# How can I intercept the click on add Attachement button in Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I need to build a visual studion Addin to intercept the click on the standard button "Add Attachement" in outlook 2010. Could someone give me some tips to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MailItem.BeforeAttachmentAdd Event

Here is the Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869219(v=office.14).aspx

The link also provides several events you can hook into related to attachments.